# How to read Texts/Numbers from a File in C

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have this code to write a file named `Phone Bill.txt`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("Phone Bill.txt","w");

    if(file!=NULL){
        fprintf(file, "Number\t\tLocal Call Chargers\tInternational Call Charges\tRoaming Charges\n");
    }

    double phoneNumber; 
    float localCharges, internationalCharges, roamingCharges;
    char wantToContinue='Y';

    while(wantToContinue=='Y'){
        printf("Enter Phone Number: ");
        scanf("%lf",&phoneNumber);
        printf("Enter Local Call Charges: ");
        scanf("%f",&localCharges);
        printf("Enter International Call Charges: ");
        scanf("%f",&internationalCharges);
        printf("Enter Roaming Call Charges: ");
        scanf("%f",&roamingCharges);

        if (file!=NULL)
        fprintf(file, "%.0lf\t%.0f\t\t\t%.0f\t\t\t\t%.0f\n",phoneNumber,localCharges,internationalCharges,roamingCharges);

        printf("\n");
        printf("Want to Continue Writing? (Y/N)");  
        scanf(" %c",&wantToContinue);
        if(wantToContinue=='Y'){
                wantToContinue='Y';
        }else if(wantToContinue=='N'){
                wantToContinue='N';
                fclose(file);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



return 0;
}
```

Here's the screenshot of the `Phone Bill.txt` after Writing the contents to the file:

[Phone Bill Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5MdL.jpg)

This is the code I used to read the content (numbers) from the `Phone Bill.txt` file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *file;

    char strings[200];
    double phoneNumber; 
    float localCharges, internationalCharges, roamingCharges;

    file=fopen("Phone Bill.txt","r");

    if(file!=NULL){
        fscanf(file,"%.0lf\t%.0f\t\t\t%.0f\t\t\t\t%.0f\n",phoneNumber,localCharges,internationalCharges,roamingCharges);
        printf("%.0lf %0.f %0.f %0.f",phoneNumber,localCharges,internationalCharges,roamingCharges);
    }
return 0;
}
```

But my Output is:

> 0 0 0 0

**Can you please tell me why am I getting this error???***

Thank you!

Comment: You do realise that `scanf` retuns a value

Comment: (Besides pointing to the destination variables, you need to account for the first line in the file, whose entries are not numeric.)

Comment: It would have been much easier, since the file is already formatted to type, at a terminal (in windows) "type 'phone bill.txt'"  (in linux) "cat 'phone bill.txt'"    However, placing a space in the middle of the file name is (almost) always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are trying to scan the first line of the file which is **headings**.

Secondly, you need to remove all the noise from the `fscanf` format definitions: those format types automatically ignore leading whitespace.

Thirdly, you need to pass *addresses* to `fscanf`. Here is a working edit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    char strings[200];
    double phoneNumber; 
    float localCharges, internationalCharges, roamingCharges;
    file=fopen("Phone Bill.txt","r");
    if(file!=NULL){
        fgets(strings, sizeof strings, file);       // read the headings
        fscanf(file,"%lf%f%f%f", &phoneNumber, &localCharges, &internationalCharges, &roamingCharges);
        printf("%.0lf %0.f %0.f %0.f", phoneNumber, localCharges, internationalCharges, roamingCharges);
        fclose(file);                               // don't forget to close
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, you must check the return value from `fscanf` which should be `4` the number of items scanned.

Lastly, I suggest that `phoneNumber` should not be `double` or even `unsigned long long`, but something like `char phoneNumber[MAXPHLEN]`. Phone numbers can begin with a `0` or `00` which will otherwise be lost. More generally, that will also accommodate the `+` used in IDD and the alphabetic equivalents of numbers which were, and perhaps still are, used on some phone dials.

**EDIT** from the OP's comment about using a string for a phone number. I restrict the string input length to prevent overflow, and also check the number of items scanned - in a loop to read all the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXPHLEN 50

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    char strings[200];
    char phoneNumber[MAXPHLEN];
    float localCharges, internationalCharges, roamingCharges;
    file=fopen("Phone Bill.txt","r");
    if(file!=NULL){
        fgets(strings, sizeof strings, file);       // read the headings
        while((fscanf(file,"%49s%f%f%f", phoneNumber, &localCharges, &internationalCharges, &roamingCharges)) == 4) {
            printf("%s %0.f %0.f %0.f\n", phoneNumber, localCharges, internationalCharges, roamingCharges);
        }
        fclose(file);                               // don't forget to close
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And can you please tell me about the `char[MAXPHLEN]` and how to use it?

Comment: and can you please tell me how can I get the second number and its realated data?

Comment: Thanks and why do we equal the `fscanf` data to 4?

Comment: and what's the meaning of this part Sir? **"%49s%f%f%f"**

Comment: I have revised the edit to read all the file. That's enough now: please read the man pages for the `scanf` family, to find out what the function return value means (although I already metioned that), as I already mentioned you must restrict the string input length.

Comment: Thank you SO much Sir :)

Comment: Reading using a mix of `fgets()` and `fscanf(file,"%49s%f%f%f"...` uses 2 approaches that rarely work well together.  Although they do work here, reading _lines_ of input with `fgets()` only is better

Answer (score 0):

Change your fscanf to point to the variables:

So:

```
fscanf(file,"%.0lf\t%.0f\t\t\t%.0f\t\t\t\t%.0f\n",&phoneNumber,&localCharges,&internationalCharges,&roamingCharges)
```

Answer (score 0):

in general, should always make code as simple as possible (and no simpler)

The following proposed code:

1. compiles cleanly
2. performs the desired functionality

Note: since the file is already formatted, only need to echo the lines to the terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fgets(), fopen(), fclose(), puts(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main( void )
{
    char strings[200];

    FILE *fp = fopen("Phone Bill.txt","r");
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read Phone Bill.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    // read, print each line:
    while( fgets( strings, sizeof( strings ), fp ) )
    {
        puts( strings );
    }

    if( !feof( fp ) )
    { // then read error
        perror( "read of Phone Bill.txt failed" );
        fclose( fp );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fclose( fp );
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

regarding the OPs posted code to read the file:

a `\t` is 'white space', so should not be in the `fscanf()` format string

The first line of the file is not part of the data, so needs to be read in separately, Suggest using `fgets()` to read into `strings[]` then can immediately echo with `puts()`

the second line through the end of the file can be easily read with:

```
while( 4 == fscanf( file, " %lf %f %f %f", &phoneNumber, &localCharges, &internationalCharges, &roamingCharges ) ) 
{
    ....
}
```

the format string for the `fscanf()`  can be reduced further (because %f and %lf input/format specifications discard leading 'white space' to:

```
"%lf%f%f%f"
```